# Share Same resource in multiple Container in docker

Tags: docker, share, volume

I need to setup one container volume use to multiple container.

for example:

```
   Container 1(web app1): volume path -v /var/www/html/
   Container 2 (web app2): volume path -v /var/www/html/
   Container 3(Commaon Files): volume path -v /var/www/html/
```

I need to setup Container-3 Common file use other two Containers.

How can I Achive this.

Comment: According to the [docker volume documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/), "Data volumes can be shared and reused among containers." 

So, have you tried just by mapping the containers to the same shared host volume?

Answer (score 3):

You should name your volumes so you can mount them by name instead of by container. So:

```
docker run -d --name web1 -v web1-html:/var/www/html web-img
docker run -d --name web2 -v web2-html:/var/www/html web-img
docker run -d --name common -v web1-html:/var/www/web1/html \
  -v web2-html:/var/www/web2/html your-img
```

With the volumes created today from your two web apps, you'll see them listed with a guid under `docker volume ls`. By giving them a name, you can easily reused those volumes in other containers.